# Show click menu item

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following dropdown menu;

```
                <ul class="dd-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span><img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/crm/1.png"></span>1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span><img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/crm/2.png"></span>2</a>
                </li></ul>
```

I get the selected text by writing

```
menuApp = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('nav, #header-middle' ),
events: {
    'click .dd-menu li a': 'optionChange'
},
optionChange: function(e) {
   console.log(e.currentTarget);
}});
```

Can anyone help me to show/change selected item (1 or 2) in the dropdown menu when I click the item?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to use a special event.

Inside your route add this:

```
index: function() {
    Backbone.trigger('route:index');
}
```

And inside your view you should listen that event:

```
initialize: fucntion() {
    this.listenTo(Backbone, 'router:index', function() {
      console.log('index page was selected');
});
```